# How do I render a user's previous session with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, local-storage

I am building a webapp using React js that allows users to add text, alter it, add images, alter them, and upload their own images.

I want to be able to reload the page as they left it if they close the tab or go to a different page. I know that I can store with localStorage, however I am having trouble rendering that when they return to that page. How do I inject that localStorage into the body so that it renders that session?

I'm using the MERN stack to handle user data. But in this case I don't necessarily want to store the JSON string representation of the page. I just want to keep it in the browser's local storage, and render the elements as they were before the user left (position, dimensions, etc).

Comment: It really depends on how you are populating the data in React in the first place from a "new" state. Assuming you are storing that data in some state, whether with Redux or some other mechanism, then turning that in to properties - you would load the localStorage data and use it to set the values on that object.

Comment: This is the purpose that global state serves, Redux in particular. If nested components use their own `state`, you're out of luck. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Are you using Redux or just pure react?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the web application to show user data you'll need to use some sort of database. MySQL and PostgreSQL are great SQL databases. If you've never worked with a SQL database before MySQL is good to start off with. If you don't want to use a SQL database you can use a NoSQL database which uses .json files to represent your data. There are tools to help you manage .json data files like mongoDB. Note if you plan on scaling this application really large SQL databases are better where as a NoSQL database are more suited for prototyping.

Also you will need a hosting server to download these databases and serve your content to the public web. The are many cloud hosting providers out there like Amazon web services, Microsoft Azure, Google Cloud, Digital Ocean, and Linode to name a few of the more popular ones.

Comment: I'm using the MERN stack to handle user data. But in this case I don't necessarily want to store the JSON string representation of the page. I just want to keep it in the browser's local storage, and render the elements as they were before the user left (position, dimensions, etc).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you would do that without a database. Maybe trying looking into storing data as browser cookies. The only issue with cookies through is I think they expire after a set amount of time. [See MDN explanation of cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie). Also cookies have security risks. You might be able to eliminate risks if you have an SSL certificate installed and can reach your domain name at https://.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

*localState.js*

```
export const clearState = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem('state');
}

export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const state = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if (state === null) {
      return {};
    }

    return JSON.parse(state)
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn('%c load state error', 'color: #b00', err);
  }
};

export const saveState = (state) => {
  try {
    localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(state));
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn('%c save state error', 'color: #b00', err);
  }
};
```

*index.js*

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import reducers from './reducers.js';
import { clearState, loadState, saveState} from './localState.js';

const initialState = loadState();

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)), // not necessary, but nice for debugging
);

// save the state whenever the Redux store changes
store.subscribe(() => {
  const state = store.getState();
  if (state.user.signOut) {
    clearState();
  } else {
    saveState(store.getState());
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppRoot store={store} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

---

One caveat is that if you ever change the schema, you'll want to blow away the saved state to avoid weird bugs. Or you could use schema versioning.